# LibGDX Label Not Drawing

Tags: java, label, libgdx, draw, scene2d

I'm trying to draw a LibGDX label on the screen for my game's help screen but, I don't get any errors from the JVM but the label text just won't draw.

This is my HelpMenu class:

```
package metrovelox.screens;

//imports...
public class HelpMenu extends Screen {

    private Stage stage;

    public HelpMenu(Game game, String name) {
        super(game, name);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        Texture.setEnforcePotImages(false);

        stage = new Stage();

        Group background = new Group();
        Group foreground = new Group();

        background.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
        foreground.setBounds(0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        stage.addActor(background);
        stage.addActor(foreground);

        background.addActor(ResourceLoader.loadImage("ui/Main Menu Background.jpg"));

        TextButton back = new TextButton("back", GuiSkinRegistry.retrieve("Simple Buttons"));
        back.setPosition(Utils.getScreenCenter().x - 186, Utils.getScreenCenter().y - 200);

        Label text = new Label("Hello", GuiSkinRegistry.retrieve("Simple Label"));
        text.setPosition(Utils.getScreenCenter().x, Utils.getScreenCenter().y);

        back.addListener(new ClickListener(Buttons.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
                getGame().setScreen(getGame().getScreen("Main Menu"));
            }
        });

        foreground.addActor(back);
        foreground.addActor(text);

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(stage);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        super.render(delta);
        stage.act(delta);
        stage.draw();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        super.dispose();
        stage.dispose();
    }

}
```

And this is my main Game class:

```
package metrovelox.core;

import metrovelox.screens.HelpMenu;
import metrovelox.screens.MainMenu;

public class Metrovelox extends Game {

    @Override
    public void init() {
        //Register skins, screens etc...
        GuiSkinRegistry.register("Simple Buttons", ResourceLoader.loadSkin("MainMenu", ResourceLoader.loadTextureAtlas("ui/simple_buttons")));
        GuiSkinRegistry.register("Simple Label", ResourceLoader.loadSkin("HelpMenu"));

        addScreen(new MainMenu(this, "Main Menu"));
        addScreen(new HelpMenu(this, "Help Menu"));


        setScreen(getScreen("Main Menu"));
    }

}
```

This is my skin file:

```
{
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Color: {
        white: { hex: "ffffff" }
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont: {
        impact: {file: "../fonts/impact.fnt"}
    },
    com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.ui.Label$LabelStyle: {
        default: {
            font: impact, fontColor: white
        }
    }
}
```

This is a screenshot of the help screen:
[image: Screenshot]

As you can see, the label is not being drawn at all. All the files are in the correct places and all the code seems to be correct from what I could gather from the LibGDX documentation but the label won't draw.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this, I seem to having a similar issue too. =[

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the font file.  Perhaps it is something to do with setting the color to White.  I've had some very strange errors with fonts, and had to play with the output from [Angel Code site](http://www.angelcode.com/products/bmfont/) version 1.14 to finally get it right.  1.13 did Not work for me.